# How to redirect to a top route from a nested route with node express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

How can I redirect to a top route from a nested route?

On the code below, the callback for the route `/toproute/nested` should redirect to `/profile` instead of `/toproute/profile`.

```js
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const topRoutes = require('./top-routes');

app.use('/toproute', topRoutes);

app.use('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.send('About');
});

app.listen(4200, () => {});
```

```js
// top-routes.js - /toproute

const router = require('express').Router();

router.use('/nested', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/profile'); // Should redirect to /profile instead of /toproute/profile
}););
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As express [document](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html), you can pass a relative path to `redirect`.

In your case, you can use `res.redirect('../profile');` instead of `res.redirect('/profile');`

Comment: Totally worked. I can't believe I didn't think of that.